# Python : batch up a number of readings and send in json

Tags: python, json, mqtt

I'm a little confused by JSON and Python objects, I've read up a lot on python dictionaries but still no look.  I have a Raspberry Pi with a sensor to read pressure.  I want to batch up a number of readings and send to MQTT server.  I want the output of the data to look like:

```
{'pressure': 2, 'time': 1529923890.237}
{'pressure': 5, 'time': 1529923890.247}
{'pressure': 9, 'time': 1529923890.258}
{'pressure': 2, 'time': 1529923890.268}
{'pressure': 6, 'time': 1529923890.278}
{'pressure': 2, 'time': 1529923890.288}
```

The example code i have is :

```
import json
import time
from decimal import Decimal

count = 0
read_pressures = {}
while (count < 100):
    current_time=time.time()
    data = dict(pressure=2,time=current_time)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    count = count + 1
    print( data) #
    read_pressures = data
print ("printing all values")
print(read_pressures)
```

All I get is the last value.  Is it best practice to put all items into a dictionary and then convert to json or should i just put straight into a string in json format?

Comment: `read_pressures = data` reassigns the value of `read_pressure` every time you iterate. This overwrites the previous value. Is this really what you want? Where are you using MQTT? To do what you want, you should send the message each time in the loop.

Comment: Alternatively, you can gather a list of measurements and send them all at the same time. If you want to do this, you need to learn about lists in python.

Comment: Good questions.  This is where my thinking is probably going awry.  I've been sending them in the loop but it creates to much network traffic so i want to gather in a list like you said and then send them on as a batch.  Are you saying dictionaries are the wrong thing to use? should i be using a list? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Dictionaries are fine...but notice the plurality here. That suggest you need a **list** of dictionaries (so you are using lists and dictionaries in combination, not dictionaries in isolation).

Comment: Where does your code send anything? How is this specific to MQTT?

Comment: @resolver101 I improve your code in answer section, maybe taht help you up.

Answer (score 3):

Two issues with your code.

```
read_pressures = {}
```

creates a dictionary but you have a list of items, 
so a list would suit your purpose better

```
read_pressures = []
```

Another problem is with

```
read_pressures = data
```

You simply reassign the value of `read_pressures` each time, but you need to collect `data` dicts instead, so

```
read_pressures.append(data)
```

will yield you the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends how you need your data to be sent. You are also overwriting `read_pressures` with every pass of the loop.

```
import json
import time
from decimal import Decimal

count = 0
read_pressures = []
while (count < 100):
    current_time=time.time()
    data = dict(pressure=2,time=current_time)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    count = count + 1
    print(data) #
    read_pressures.append(data)
print ("printing all values")
print(read_pressures)
```

Answer (score 0):

I improve your code:

```
import pprint
import time
from datetime import datetime

read_pressures = list()
for _ in range(100):
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    data = dict(pressure=2, time=current_time)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    read_pressures.append(data)

pprint.pprint(read_pressures)
```